# Wrapping issues when using Masonry with Bootstrap Columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-masonry

I have a news article page, where i can specify the width of the articles like this :

```
<div class="<%# GetArticleSize(Item.ArticleSize) %>">
```

Which renders the box elements in one of the following :

- col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6  (small size)
- col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6  (half size)
- col-xs-12 (full size)

The masonry layout works perfectly if all the news-articles are col-sm-3 (look at this link [HERE](http://www.gjovikhk.no/) for the perfect result when using this)..

The issue comes when i set one of the news-articles as col-sm-6 (half page size).. 
See this image : [image]

It seems like it's not enough room for last col-sm-3 element, and it wraps underneath, and creating a weird look on all other news-articles.

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/x3trjyrw/3/) to illustrate the code.. BUT.. this code works and wraps like it should..

I have no idea what's causing this.. Maybe one of you have any idea how to make this correct ?

**UPDATED !!**
When i changed the masonry target from the container to the grid *items* itself, it atleast spanned the whole width, but it is too wide..

```
$('.grid-item').masonry({
    columnWidth: 200
});

 <asp:ListView ID="lvArticles" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" ItemType="Servicelayer.Article" OnItemCommand="lvArticles_OnItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="lvArticles_OnItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="grid-item <%# GetArticleSize(Item.ArticleSize) %>">
```

Which... renders into :

```html
<div id="article-list" class="widget-container row">
        
                <div class="grid-item widget-news widget-box col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="position: relative; height: 277.5px;">
                    <div class="action-container" style="position: absolute; left: 15px; top: 0px;">
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="widget-content visible priority" style="position: absolute; left: 15px; top: 0px;">
                        <div class="header">
                            <p>
                                <a id="MainContent_lvArticles_lnkViewArticle_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$lvArticles$ctrl0$lnkViewArticle','')">A-lagsjentene på oppdrag for CC Gjøvik</a>
                            </p>
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row item">
                            <p>
                                
                                </p><div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <img class="article-image" src="http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/images/125895ba-b174-4356-93f2-2371f1a84403logo_Deloitte.png">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 article-image-subtext">
                                    Mari Finstad Bergum og Emma Fauchald 
                                </div>
                                
                                
                                <p class="articletags"></p>
                            <p></p>

                        </div>
                        <div class="widget-content-footer">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="avatar-container">
                                                <img class="avatar" src="https://klubbweb.blob.core.windows.net/clubid21/81ae3567-3038-4299-9d91-8365ffef185bavatar24.jpg" enableviewstate="False">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                            <div class="created-by">
                                                <p>Marthe Godtlund Bråthen</p>
                                                <p>19.09.2016 11:46</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
                <div class="grid-item widget-news widget-box col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6" style="position: relative; height: 493.5px;">
                    <div class="action-container" style="position: absolute; left: 15px; top: 0px;">
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="widget-content visible priority" style="position: absolute; left: 15px; top: 0px;">
                        <div class="header">
                            <p>
                                <a id="MainContent_lvArticles_lnkViewArticle_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$lvArticles$ctrl1$lnkViewArticle','')">NM-gull til ni Gjøvik HK-jenter!</a>
                            </p>
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row item">
                            <p>
                                
                                </p><div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <img class="article-image" src="https://klubbweb.blob.core.windows.net/clubid21/da2d0d26-e00e-4b10-84db-76adf999ba6eIMG_6263.JPG">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 article-image-subtext">
                                    Region Innlandet med ni Gjøvik HK-jenter kunne juble for gull i region-NM.
                                </div>
                                
                                
                                <p class="articletags">Tags: Region-Nm 2016, Nm-Gull, Nm-Gullvm-Gull,  Nm-Gull,  Nm-Gullvm-Gull</p>
                            <p></p>

                        </div>
                        <div class="widget-content-footer">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="avatar-container">
                                                <img class="avatar" src="https://klubbweb.blob.core.windows.net/clubid21/81ae3567-3038-4299-9d91-8365ffef185bavatar24.jpg" enableviewstate="False">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                            <div class="created-by">
                                                <p>Marthe Godtlund Bråthen</p>
                                                <p>25.04.2016 17:45</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
                <div class="grid-item widget-news widget-box col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6" style="position: relative; height: 317px;">
                    <div class="action-container" style="position: absolute; left: 15px; top: 0px;">
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="widget-content visible" style="position: absolute; left: 15px; top: 0px;">
                        <div class="header">
                            <p>
                                <a id="MainContent_lvArticles_lnkViewArticle_2" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$lvArticles$ctrl2$lnkViewArticle','')">Dokument nå da ? </a>
                            </p>
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row item">
                            <p>
                                
                                </p><div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <img class="article-image" src="http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/images/5695dc5d-c580-4cd2-94dd-4ab853539839bgyeah.jpg">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 article-image-subtext">
                                    
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <a style="text-decoration: underline" target="_blank" class="article-text" href="http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/images/6803c4b4-0c8c-4f20-a613-13ab72bf7ec7Hekk planter barlind bestilling.xlsx">Hekk planter barlind bestilling.xlsx</a>
                                </div>
                                <p class="articletags"></p>
                            <p></p>

                        </div>
                        <div class="widget-content-footer">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="avatar-container">
                                                <img class="avatar" src="http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/images/875bcc1f-5d70-4d74-88bd-55deb482ec9favatar5.jpg" enableviewstate="False">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                            <div class="created-by">
                                                <p>Terje Nygård</p>
                                                <p>31.03.2017 19:57</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
                <div class="grid-item widget-news widget-box col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6" style="position: relative; height: 159px;">
                    <div class="action-container" style="position: absolute; left: 15px; top: 0px;">
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="widget-content visible" style="position: absolute; left: 15px; top: 0px;">
                        <div class="header">
                            <p>
                                <a id="MainContent_lvArticles_lnkViewArticle_3" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$lvArticles$ctrl3$lnkViewArticle','')">Dokument ? </a>
                            </p>
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row item">
                            <p>
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                </p><p class="articletags"></p>
                            <p></p>

                        </div>
                        <div class="widget-content-footer">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="avatar-container">
                                                <img class="avatar" src="http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/images/875bcc1f-5d70-4d74-88bd-55deb482ec9favatar5.jpg" enableviewstate="False">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                            <div class="created-by">
                                                <p>Terje Nygård</p>
                                                <p>31.03.2017 19:53</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
                <div class="grid-item widget-news widget-box col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6" style="position: relative; height: 326px;">
                    <div class="action-container" style="position: absolute; left: 15px; top: 0px;">
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="widget-content visible" style="position: absolute; left: 15px; top: 0px;">
                        <div class="header">
                            <p>
                                <a id="MainContent_lvArticles_lnkViewArticle_4" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$lvArticles$ctrl4$lnkViewArticle','')">Test..</a>
                            </p>
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row item">
                            <p>
                                
                                </p><div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                    <img class="article-image" src="http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/images/a51d287c-d160-4ba4-9765-aae2cf185973boss.jpg">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 article-image-subtext">
                                    Boss.
                                </div>
                                
                                
                                <p class="articletags"></p>
                            <p></p>

                        </div>
                        <div class="widget-content-footer">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="avatar-container">
                                                <img class="avatar" src="http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/images/875bcc1f-5d70-4d74-88bd-55deb482ec9favatar5.jpg" enableviewstate="False">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                            <div class="created-by">
                                                <p>Terje Nygård</p>
                                                <p>31.03.2017 19:51</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
                <div class="grid-item widget-news widget-box col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6" style="position: relative; height: 160px;">
                    <div class="action-container" style="position: absolute; left: 15px; top: 0px;">
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="widget-content visible" style="position: absolute; left: 15px; top: 0px;">
                        <div class="header">
                            <p>
                                <a id="MainContent_lvArticles_lnkViewArticle_5" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$lvArticles$ctrl5$lnkViewArticle','')">Møtereferat ja</a>
                            </p>
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row item">
                            <p>
                                
                                
                                
                                
                                </p><div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <a style="text-decoration: underline" target="_blank" class="article-text" href="http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/images/987ceade-e6db-430b-84ac-c23e1194a3b1Håndball - Øvelser og program.docx"></a>
                                </div>
                                <p class="articletags"></p>
                            <p></p>

                        </div>
                        <div class="widget-content-footer">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <div class="avatar-container">
                                                <img class="avatar" src="http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/images/875bcc1f-5d70-4d74-88bd-55deb482ec9favatar5.jpg" enableviewstate="False">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                            <div class="created-by">
                                                <p>Terje Nygård</p>
                                                <p>31.03.2017 18:44</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
    </div>
```

I end up with a result which looks like this :

[image]

Comment: I believe you have some issues with your fiddle; check the console. I think you just need to include jQuery before bootstrap. :)

Comment: Also, I'm not 100% sure but your problem may be because Masonary doesn't support those types of layouts; I suggest you check out Packery which will do what you want as I have used it to do something similar in the past.

Comment: Sorry for late answer @Brett :) Ok.. i have understood that "automagic" that masonry does by now, and it seems when using different sizes on the "boxes", the last item on the row which ... wraps.. gets positioned underneath the first one in some way.. 

Is there a chance.. you can show me how i can do this with Packery ? Would be nice to know if it's "doable" with this, before i pay 25$ for it :)

Comment: I've only used Packery the once and it was over a year ago now, but this is what I did with it: http://easifleet.com.au/about-us/ - As you can see I didn't use bootstraps `col-*` classes but rather my own, but this may have been because I had varying sizes that Bootstrap didn't support out of the box as I recall. It seems the `height*` classes weren't used after all so you can probably ignore them as seems I forgot to remove them and the larger size red box height was controlled on the child element. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Masonry FAQ: The first item breaks the grid!](http://masonry.desandro.com/faq.html#the-first-item-breaks-the-grid)

> You most likely need to set the [`columnWidth` option](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#columnwidth). Without columnWidth set, Masonry will use the width of the first item for the size of its columns.

```
$('.grid').masonry({
  columnWidth: 200
});
```

Comment: updated the question with usage, rendered result and a new screenshot.. care to take a look ? :)

Hard to get these stacked beautifully together :) Is this thing for packetry ?

Comment: Hello desandro, I am having an issue implementing masonry on my website. Do you think you could check my SO question please :D ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44853887/masonry-layout-broken-in-infinite-scroll